# Swift3でSJISを使ったURLエンコードをしたい

Tags: swift, swift3, encoding, shift-jis

Swift3にて、Shift-JISでURLをエンコードする必要が出てきたのですが、
`String.addingPercentEscapes`が非推奨になっており、代わりに`String.addingPercentEncoding`を使用するように警告が出てしまいました。

いろいろ調べてみたのですが、`String.addingPercentEscapes`を使用せずにShift-JISでURLエンコードを行う方法が分からなかったため、ご教授いただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本来なら、アプリ側をSJISに対応させるのではなく、サーバー側をUTF-8に対応させるのが筋だと思うのですが…。

AppleがSJIS対応のURLエンコード機能をiOSやSwiftの標準ライブラリーに再度付け加える可能性は極めて低いでしょうから、全部自前で処理してやる必要があります。

例えばこんな感じになるでしょう。

```
extension CharacterSet {
    static let rfc3986Unreserved = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~")
}

extension String.Encoding {
    static let windows31j = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.dosJapanese.rawValue)))
}

extension String {
    func addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters characterSet: CharacterSet, using encoding: String.Encoding) -> String {
        let stringData = self.data(using: encoding, allowLossyConversion: true) ?? Data()
        let percentEscaped = stringData.map {byte->String in
            if characterSet.contains(UnicodeScalar(byte)) {
                return String(UnicodeScalar(byte))
            } else if byte == UInt8(ascii: " ") {
                return "+"
            } else {
                return String(format: "%%%02X", byte)
            }
        }.joined()
        return percentEscaped
    }

    var sjisPercentEncoded: String {
        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .rfc3986Unreserved,  using: .windows31j)
    }
}

let escaped = "今時SJISのシステムなんて…".sjisPercentEncoded
print(escaped) //->%8D%A1%8E%9ESJIS%82%CC%83V%83X%83e%83%80%82%C8%82%F1%82%C4%81c
```

通常SJISと名乗っているシステムは、Windows拡張文字も受け取れることが多いので、上記では`String.Encoding.shiftJIS`ではなく、Windows-31J相当のエンコーディングを使用しています。

実際にこれがデコードできるかどうかは、サーバーサイドが、どうパーセントエンコーディングを処理しているかによりますので、果たして上記のコードが無事に動くかどうかはなんとも言えません。

Comment: 今回2000年代に作成されたWebページに対してスクレイピングを行うためにSJISによるパーセントエンコーディングが必要でした...。指示いただいたコード無事に動きました、ありがとうございました。

Comment: @n_atmark さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。現実の開発はいろいろ大変ですね。回答に提示したコードは、かなり一般的に作ったつもりですが、昔のサイトはパーセントエンコードを独自解釈で処理している場合もあり、うまく動かないサイトが出てくるかもしれません。何かありましたらコメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: 同じことをする必要があり参考にさせて頂いたのですが、上手くエスケープできない場合がありました。
具体的には、全角バックスラッシュは "%81%5F" となるべきが "%81_" となりました。
おそらく、2バイト目の%5Fが rfc3986Unreserved に含まれる "_" のバイトと一致するからではないかと思います。
これを回避するには、SJISの1バイト目の文字（%81〜9F、%E0〜EF）を判定して、それらが来たら次のバイトは無条件でパーセントエスケープする必要があるかと思います。
SJISのシステム早くなくしたいですね。。

Comment: @yamamoto さん、コメントありがとうございます。この回答では「全角バックスラッシュ」のような場合は意図的に`"%81_"`を出力するように作ってあります。他言語のライブラリでSJIS指定できるものや、いくつかのサイトでそれが正しくデコードされるのを調べた上でこうしたのですが、ほんの少し調べ方が違っていたら、 @yamamoto さんの書かれたような出力を出すように作っていたかもしれません。ただ、SJISを使うこと自体が標準外の処理をしているので「なるべき」と表現して良いかどうかは疑問の残るところですが。 @yamamoto さんの書かれたような出力をさせるのはそれほど大変でもありません。よろしければ別解として回答の形で書いてみてください。

Comment: @OOPer さん、確かに標準仕様があるわけではないので「なるべき」という表現は不適切だったかもしれません。
OOPerさんのコードを参考に、私の関わっているシステムの都合に合わせたコードを作ったので回答に記載しておきます。

Comment: @yamamoto さん、どう「なるべき」かと言う点で言えば、実際にターゲットにしたい相手先システムが正しく受け取れるように「なるべき」なので、チルダの処理など実際のシステムで必要だったであろう対応の入ったあなたのご回答はかなり参考になります。結局のところ私の元回答の最後の行にたどり着いちゃうのですが、世の中のシステムがもっと国際標準準拠を徹底してくれたらなぁと言うところですね。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

deprecatedの関数を使いますが、一応以下でSJISのURLエンコードができます。

```
func sjisUrlEncode(_ str: String) -> String? {

    let raw: NSString = str as NSString
    // iOS9からdeprecatedだが他にShift_JISでエスケープできる関数がない
    if var encoded = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                             raw,
                                                             nil,
                                                             ":/?&=;+!@#$()',*" as CFString,
                                                             0x0A01) as String?
    {
        encoded = encoded.replacingOccurrences(of: "~", with: "%7E") // チルダのエンコード
        encoded = encoded.replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: "+") // スペースは%20ではなく+にする
        return encoded
    }

    return nil
}
```

OOPerさんのコードを参考に、deprecatedの関数を使わず上記と同じ出力となる（たぶん）ものを作りました。

```
import UIKit

class SJISURLEncoder {
    private static let windows31j = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.dosJapanese.rawValue)))

    private static let rfc3986Unreserved = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~"

    private static let specialConversionMap: [Character: String] = [
        " ":"+",
        "¥":"%5C",
        "\\":"%81%5F", // バックスラッシュは全角バックスラッシュに変換
        "~":"%7E" // チルダは古いシステムではエスケープが必要な場合がある
    ]

    // SJISでURLエンコードする
    class func encode(_ src: String) -> String {

        let percentEscaped = src.map { c -> String in

            if let converted = specialConversionMap[c] {
                return converted
            } else if rfc3986Unreserved.contains(c) {
                return String(c)
            }

            let stringData = String(c).data(using: windows31j, allowLossyConversion: true) ?? Data()
            return stringData.map {byte -> String in
                return String(format: "%%%02X", byte)
            }.joined()

        }.joined()

        return percentEscaped
    }
}
```

※Swift3だとsrc.mapはsrc.characters.mapとなるかもしれません。